# Angular-CLI AngularJS + Angular with Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, git, angular, kendo-ui, angular-cli

I trying to make an AngularJS + Angular4 Hybrid Project with Angular-CLI.
Surely i'm not alone with this approach... :)

So far I'm struggeling to include Kendo UI for JQuery in the CLI Project.
Why Kendo UI for JQuery? Because our AngularJS-Side of the Project uses it.
The Angular 4+ side would use the new Kendo UI for Angular.

This is what I did so far...

1. I added "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" under scripts in the angular-cli.json file
   (Because JQuery is needed to use Kendo UI for JQuery obviously)
2. I created a vendor.ts File and added the dependency "import '../node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.js'"

Then i get this error:
"Module 'kendo.directives' is not available! 
 You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
 If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Maybe an Angular-cli-Crack can take a look at my project and could give me some hints. Because the Kendo-Support is just disappointing...

https://github.com/dialogaal/angular-hybrid-kendo